# Background can't position right

Tags: html, css

hi guys i'm new to html and css
i wanted to create 4 backgrounds one at top one at left one at bottom and one at right... but somehow the one at right doesn't show up and the other work fine
can you help me?

HTML:

```
    <div class="header">
    </div>

    <div class="leftheader">
    </div>

    <div class="rightheader">
    </div>

    <div class="bottomheader">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: arial

}


.header{
    background: #cccccc;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}

.leftheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: 100;
    height: 590;
}

.rightheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right 10px top 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100;
    height: 590;
}

.bottomheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key to getting this to work is using `float: left` and `float: right` on your `.leftheader` and `.rightheader` elements. Then you need to clear your floats by putting `clear: both` on the `.bottomheader`.

```css
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: arial
}
.header {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}
.leftheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: left;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 590px;
    float: left;
}
.rightheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right 10px top 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 590px;
    float: right;
}
.bottomheader {
    background: #cccccc;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: bottom;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="leftheader">leftheader</div>
<div class="rightheader">rightheader</div>
<div class="bottomheader">bottomheader</div>
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!